# How to aggregate the text from file

Tags: java

My usecase is to display the data from java command line app. Here is the sample data inside input.txt file which user will enter via command line:

```
  // (booking date , Empid)
    2011-03-17 10:17:06 EMP001
 //  (appointment date, duration)
    2011-03-21 09:00 2
    2011-03-16 12:34:56 EMP002
    2011-03-21 09:00 2
    2011-03-16 09:28:23 EMP003
    2011-03-22 14:00 2
    2011-03-17 11:23:45 EMP004
    2011-03-22 16:00 1
    2011-03-15 17:29:12 EMP005
    2011-03-21 16:00
```

And my output should aggregate via appointment date from output.txt file, Day-wise appointments as :

```
2011-03-21
09:00 11:00 EMP002
2011-03-22
14:00 16:00 EMP003
16:00 17:00 EMP004
```

What would be the right approach, and logic to perform such functionality.

I am doing write operations on two files: input.txt which is getting store in proper format, but from output.txt I want the output should be of format as mentioned above. Below is how i am getting store the object in output.txt file :

```
static boolean writeToOutputFile(Booking booking){
        boolean flag = true;
        try {
            FileWriter fout = new FileWriter(outputFile);
            fout.write(booking.getMeetingDate());
            fout.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            fout.write(booking.getStartTime()+" "+booking.getEndTime()+" "+booking.getEmpId());
            fout.flush();
            fout.close();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            flag = false;
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

output.txt :

```
2011-03-21
09:00 11:00 EMP003
2011-03-21
09:00 11:00 EMP001
2011-03-21
12:00 14:00 EMP002
```

Thanks

Comment: The right approach is to start a Java project and try something.

Comment: Yes, setted up java project and already started the work, looking for some advice to start in right direction rather to rework again due to time constraints. I do try with something at logic part then update the problem

Comment: Basically you need to group your data by date. Read your file line by line, split each line into 3 fields (date, time. event). Keep a `Map<String, List<...>>` that maps date strings to a list of objects containing time and event name. Then sort the keys of that map and iterate over the map, extracting and printing events. It seems you'd want to group the events by time; use a similar map.

Comment: Please attempt a solution and if you get stuck somewhere, post a question here.

Comment: Hi Guys, I have updated the post. Let me know in case have any idea.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class for each appointment, and then parse the input.txt file using Regular Expressions. Then you could sort the appointment-objects (for example with the Comparable-Interface and then sort the Objects with Collections.sort() ) If the grouping is important you could only include the time in your appointment object and use a Map with the type Map> to do the grouping. If you need further assistance or alternative ideas, leave a comment